# Get access_token when use uxMode="redirect" on react-google-login

Tags: reactjs, access-token, google-signin

I use `react-google-login`.

I need to send `access_token` to the back-end, and when I use `uxMode="popup"`, onSuccess function is called, so I can get `access_token` from the response.

But I want to use `uxMode="redirect"`. Here is my code:

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId="..."
  buttonText="go to sign in"
  onSuccess={::this.responseGoogle}
  onFailure={::this.errorGoogle}
  onRequest={::this.onRequest}
  uxMode='redirect'
  redirectUri={window.location.origin + '/auth/google/callback'}
/>
```

It doesn't call onSuccess function and redirects to the `/auth/google/callback`. I can't get this parameter from `location.hash` (but it has id_token).

From what can I get `access_token` and is it possible at all?

Comment: I am also facing same problem. But in my case when I send the token id and use it I am not getting any profile details with that token in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code on the server side (node js) to dynamically handle the case of having an ID TOKEN and the case of having an ACCESS TOKEN.

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const unirest = require('unirest');

exports.user_google_login = async function (req, res) {
        const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
  
        const isValidIdToken = !!req.body.credential;
        //credentail refers to ID TOKEN
        
        const ticket = isValidIdToken
                     ? await client.verifyIdToken({
                       idToken: req.body.credential,
                       audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                    })
                     : await unirest
                      .get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo')
                      .headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${req.body.access_token}` })
                      .send();

        const payload = isValidIdToken ? ticket.getPayload() : ticket.body;
        //payload will hold user details
    }
```